# SQL: How to update all rows with a calculation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm trying to add in the `total price` for a pizza order based on the order `sub-total` and `tax`. I've been getting an error stating the subquery returned more than 1 value with this command:

```
DECLARE @orderTotal AS INT
SET @orderTotal = (SELECT(SUM((orderSubtotal+tax) * (1 - discountAmount)))
                   FROM OrderProcessing GROUP BY orderID)
UPDATE OrderProcessing
SET orderTotalAmount = @orderTotal
```

`discountAmount` equals a decimal number like `0.2` to represent a `20%` discount.

Comment: the query u r using for update is returning more rows..u should put a where clause which will return one value for seting the @ordertotal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, this is the wrong way to do it, unless you want all the orders to have the same value in `orderTotalAmount` column.
I think you are probably looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE OrderProcessing
SET orderTotalAmount = (orderSubtotal + tax) * (1 - discountAmount)
```

Second, I think you have too many brackets in your first query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need a group by but instead it should be something like

```
UPDATE OrderProcessing o
SET orderTotalAmount =
    (SELECT(SUM((orderSubtotal + tax) * (1 - discountAmount)))
    FROM OrderProcessing
    WHERE orderID = o.orderId)
```

Otherwise, as the error states, the subquery returns more than one record.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually limit the row returned from the subquery to one by using some function.

MYSQL:

```
   SELECT column_name(s)
   FROM table_name
   LIMIT number;
```

Oracle:

```
   select *
   from  
   ( //your query here ) 
   where ROWNUM = 1;
```

Or:

```
    SELECT column_name(s)
    FROM table_name
    FETCH FIRST N ROWS;
```

Hope its help :)

Comment: If you know its a incomplete answer why not complete it?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @orderTotal INT, @orderID int
SELECT @orderTotal = SUM((orderSubtotal+tax) * (1 - discountAmount)) 
FROM OrderProcessing 
WHERE orderID = @orderID 
GROUP BY orderID

UPDATE OrderProcessing
SET orderTotalAmount = @orderTotal
WHERE orderID = @orderID
```

If i understood correctly you need to update many rows in your OrderProcessing table with a unique value

Answer (score 0):

The original query returns a row for every orderID. 
After that you want to update the orderTotalAmount, but you do not specify which for which orderID.
Obviously you want to update all orders in the same way.
For that you need sfrutig approach.
You need to specify in the query which orderID you are handling, giving one row back.
And use this in a loop to update all orders.

As I do not have enough points, I could not place this comment next to sfrutig's solution.